# is possible angular bootstrap $modal with two controllers

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I need a modal to contain two controllers in order to reuse code. One of them is defined in the open function and the other one inside the template. The internal one controls only some part of the template.

The two controllers will communicate by means of events.
I am geeting this exception: "Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$injector/unpr?p0=%24modalInstanceProvider%20%3C-%20%24modalInstance%20%3C-%20InnerCtr

Is it possible to use two controllers within a modal?

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'components/template1.html',
    controller:  'PrincipalCtr'
});



<div>
  ...
  <div ng-controller="InnerCtrl">
  ...
  </div>
  ...
</div>

ngModule.controller('PrincipalCtr',['$scope','$rootScope','$modalInstance', ...
ngModule.controller('InnerCtr',['$scope','$rootScope','$modalInstance', ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the controllerAs syntax in both the code for the modal instance and the template.

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'components/template1.html',
    controller:  'PrincipalCtr as pCtrl'
});
```

and

```
<div ng-controller="InnerCtrl as innerCtrl">
```

By doing this, you can explicitly call which controller you want to use by prefixing your method with the controller.  If you have an onclick function inside one of your Principal controller, then you can say in your template,

```
<div ng-click=pCtrl.onClick()</div>
```

That being said, the exception you're getting is an injection error.  I don't think that it's a problem with there being two controllers.